# Special characters outputed from MySQL works, but when I add charset-utf8 it doesnt. Why?

Tags: html, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm creating a webpage where I need to use the special characters "Æ", "Ø", and "Å". These are all within UTF-8.

I've set up a newsfeed where I output text from MySQL. My MySQL table is set to UTF-8, and the text works perfectly fine, no weird characters or anything. Though, the pure HTML on my page where these characters are there are weird signs like "Ã¸" instead of "ø".

So I decided to add the following in my head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Sure, now the "ø" is outputted as an "ø". Though, now my text that is echoed from the MySQL screws up and displays question marks like "�" this instead.

So I'm basically stuck with a choice of having one of them display wrong. Any suggestions?

The webpage: http://lasse.orangee.me/o/bestevent/
Now, if I add the meta tag with charset=utf8 the header text displays correctly, but the news on the bottom left doesn't display correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the database connection to use UTF-8.
How to do this depends on your setup, i.e. programming language.

Comment: Not only the database table needs to be set to UTF-8 (e.g. via phpMyAdmin), but also the database connection that you create with your PHP page (or whatever language you use)

Comment: And how do I do that? :)

Comment: Well as I said, that depends on the programming language you use and the database access method you use (for example: php with pdo: `$link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB;charset=UTF8");`, copied from http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)