# Special characters not showing on the web page after set to charset=UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, apache, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an app that developed with JS, PHP and for some reason it is not able to display the Spanish Accents in the dropdown box which the values are from the mysql table.  For the same app, it display those Spanish accents without any problem on the windows web server IIS 8.5, but not in the Linux box which running REL 6.5 with apache 2.2 installed.

Here are what I did try and checked.

The charset=UTF-8 already set in the meta header in the html. The php.ini on both servers are set default to UTF-8

Default charset for Apache config file is set to UTF-8.

Checked the locale setting on Linux box to make sure include the es-UTF8 in the sysconfig.

Checked the chrome dev tool by inspect the response header and the content-type showing plain/html , charset=UTF-8, vary: accept encoding.

If I go into the phpMyAdmin and look at the raw table, the accents are stored in the MySQL table and I can search it too inside phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special characters outputed from MySQL works, but when I add charset-utf8 it doesnt. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950471/special-characters-outputed-from-mysql-works-but-when-i-add-charset-utf8-it-doe)

Comment: I don't want to troll, but every problem I had until now about character encoding was due to Windows. I would advise you to check if the working case with IIS is not actually using any Windows specific encoding charset that woul be compliant with UTF8 but which would not work on an other OS (the fact that the accent looks well in phpmyadmin, doesn't mean it is well encoded).

Comment: And in database what is the collate type of column?

Comment: Hi, The database collate is utf8_general_ci and the column collate are some utf8_general_ci and or utf8_unicode_ci,  all those setting are exactly the same between the windows box and the Redhat box. mysql server set as charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below query before executing actual query:

```
mysqli_query($con, 'SET names UTF8');
```

Comment: Yes, mysqli->set_charset("utf8") did the trick and thanks for everyone.